# Supremum of uniformly converges functions goes to the supremum of the limiting function

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let ${ f_n\left(x\right):[0,1] \to  \mathbb{R} }$  uniformly convergent to function $f(x)$ which is bounded on the interval $[0,1]$. Prove the following:
${ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{[0,1]} f_n\left(x\right) = \sup_{[0,1]} f\left(x\right) }$.

I tried to show that $f$ is bounded and therefore it has a supremum $S$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$.
In addition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $n_0$ such that for every $n > n_0$ and for every $x \in [0,1]$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. I tried to put the $x_0$ instead of $x$, and replace the $f(x_0)$ with $S$, but it doesn't helped much...

How can I use the boundedness wisely?

Comment: does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226392/interchanging-limit-with-infimum-supremum

Comment: Not exactly, because in the link the functions are continues (and he use it in his answer). Here  the functions are not necessarily continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) For $x_n\in [0,1]$, assume that $\sup\ f = \lim\ f(x_n)$

Assume that $|\sup\ f-f(x_n)|<\varepsilon$ for some $n$. By pointwise convergence,
$i>i_0$ implies $|f_i(x_n)-f(x_n)|<\varepsilon$ so that $$\sup\
f_i\geq f_i(x_n)\geq \sup\ f -2\varepsilon$$ for all $i>i_0$

Hence $\lim\ \sup\ f_i\geq \sup\ f$

ii) $|\lim\ \sup\ f_i - \sup\ f_i|<\varepsilon$ for all $i>i_0$.

Further $| f_i(x_i)- \lim\ \sup\ f_i |<2\varepsilon$ for all $i>i_0$

By uniform convergence, when $i$ is large, then $|f(x_i)-f_i(x_i)|
 <
 \varepsilon$ so that $|f(x_i)-\lim\ \sup\ f_i |<3
 \varepsilon$ for large $i$.

Comment: Thanks! but why does $ \sup\ f = \lim\ f(x_n) $? The function is not necessarily continues.

Comment: $\sup\ f=\sup\ \{f(x)|x\in [0,1]\}$ so that we have a sequence $x_n\in [0,1]$

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't some assumptions in the proof:
Why does the $sup f_i$ even exist? we don't know anything about $f_i$

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded, so we can let $\|f\|_\infty =\sup\ \{ |f(x)|
|x\in [ 0,1] \}\leq 1$

Since $f_i$ goes to $f$ uniformly, then there is $N$ s.t. $i>N$
implies $\|f_i\|_\infty\leq 2$.